# Angular 5 route fallback

Tags: angular

In my app routing module, I would like to redirect the user either to the dashboard (if logged in), or the the homepage (if not logged in).

I am using a guard to make this check.

From **app-routing.module.ts**

```
 class LoggedInUser implements CanActivate {
  constructor(@Inject(LoginService) private loginService: LoginService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.loginService.isAuthenticated({
        isLoggedIn(message: string, loggedIn: boolean) {
          resolve(loggedIn);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', canActivate: [LoggedInUser] },
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/homepage/homepage.module#HomepageModule' }
];
```

This allows me to access the dashboard if I am logged in, which is what I want, but it is **not** redirecting me to the homepage otherwise.

How can I enable this fallback ? I have been searching for hours, and all I  could find was some code samples that were programmatically calling the router, to reach a dedicated path like '/login', but I don't want such a path.

Comment: You will need to use `navigate`, because your `guard` is returning `true` or `false` and just forbids the access, it doesn't `navigate away`

Comment: @NikolaGavric thanks for mentioning that I can't expect the guard to navigate away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually navigate them to login page using router, this is a rough idea that came to my mind:

```
 class LoggedInUser implements CanActivate {
  constructor(@Inject(LoginService) private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.loginService.isAuthenticated({
        isLoggedIn(message: string, loggedIn: boolean) {
          resolve(loggedIn);
        }
      });
    }).then(loggedIn => {
       if(!loggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate['login'];
       }
       return loggedIn;
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE: 7+ ( using urlTree )**

Quoted from [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/new-in-angular-v7-1-updates-to-the-router-fd67d526ad05)

> Now, for CanActivate, CanActivateChild, and CanDeactivate, there is a
>   third option; these guards can return a UrlTree directly. In these
>   scenarios, the current navigation is cancelled, and a new navigation
>   is created, which routes to the path specified by the returned
>   UrlTree. For example, if a user fails an authentication guard, you may
>   want to redirect that user directly to the login page.

Code taken from [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/new-in-angular-v7-1-updates-to-the-router-fd67d526ad05)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot,
         Router,
         UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
    const url = 'target';
    const tree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(url);
    return tree;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves the redirection problem but if forces me to suffix the url of my homepage with /login

Comment: Not sure how your routes are structured, you can search for questions on handling relative routes or ask one yourselves.

Comment: Does it really make sense to put the router re-navigation logic inside the router guard? I mean, the task of a router guard should be IMHO simply to return a `boolean`, `Promise<boolean>` or  `Observable<boolean>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski Currently they are allowing `boolean | urlTree` (updated answer), check [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/26521). If you feel this is against Single Responsibility, feel free to comment in the GitHub thread.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick: make sure you have a default route for home. I don't see it in your routes, which I think is unusual.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Additionally set up your home route:

```
path: 'home', (loadChildren if lazy loading, component if not, etc).
```

Pretty sure I had more or less the same issue here at a recent project, this did the trick with the usual guard you'd expect.